# Create JSON in for loop in Python

Tags: python, json

What i try to do is create a JSON list of bonds ... anyway idea was to create a list:

```
{
   "Country1":
   {
      "bonds": [
         {"Bond Name": "Country1 1Y","Prev. Close": 1},
         {"Bond Name": "Country1 2Y","Prev. Close": 2}
      ]
   },
   "Country2":
   {
      "bonds": [
         {"Bond Name": "Country2 1Y","Prev. Close": 1},
         {"Bond Name": "Country2 2Y","Prev. Close": 2}
      ]
   }

}
```

What i already created is another level

```
{
    "Countries": [
        {
            "Argentina": []
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what i have in code for now, and no idea how to access nested objects

```
from clear_screen import clear
clear()

import investpy
import json

json_data = {"Countries":[]}

for country_bond_item in investpy.bonds.get_bond_countries():
    # Print country name
    #print(country_bond_item.title())
    # Add value to JSON list eg: 'Argentina'
    json_data["Countries"].append({country_bond_item.title():[]})
    # Show what we have here
    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

    # Loop over country bonds
    for country_bond_list_item in investpy.bonds.get_bonds_list(country_bond_item):
        # Save JSON value for 'bond name'
        bond_json_value = investpy.bonds.get_bond_information(country_bond_list_item, as_json=True)
        # eg: {'Bond Name': 'Argentina 1Y', 'Value': '1'}
        # Just print value
        #print(bond_json_value)
        # Save bond data into: eg: json_data["Countries"]["Argentina"]
        json_data["Countries"][country_bond_item.title()].append([{'Bond Name': 'Argentina 1Y', 'Value': '1'}])

#print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

Not sure why indexing as: json_data["Countries"][country_bond_item.title()] is not working.

Where that should be: json_data["Countries"]["Argentina"] - then we can add another thing into as list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example of how to generate the json. Replace static data with your source

```py
import json

countries = ["a", "b", "c"]

bonds = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
result = {}

for country in countries:
    bonds_tmp = []
    for bond in bonds:
        bonds_tmp.append({"Bond Name": bond, "Prev. Close": 1})
    result[country] = {"bonds": bonds_tmp}

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Prints

```
{
    "a": {
        "bonds": [
            {
                "Bond Name": "b1",
                "Prev. Close": 1
            },
            {
                "Bond Name": "b2",
                "Prev. Close": 1
            },
            {
                "Bond Name": "b3",
                "Prev. Close": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "b": {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 'clean-ups' add some comments to explain what is where I have final code:

```
# Clear screen each time when run script
from clear_screen import clear
clear()

# Import libs
import investpy
import json

# Array for all countries and their bonds
json_data = {}

# Loop over all countries
for country_name in investpy.bonds.get_bond_countries():
    # Create 'array' where we can store all bonds for that country
    bonds_tmp = []
    # Loop over all bonds 
    for bond_name in investpy.bonds.get_bonds_list(country_name):
        # And add them into tmp array
        bonds_tmp.append(investpy.bonds.get_bond_information(bond_name, as_json=True))
    # Create 'country' item, that will contain array of all bonds above
    json_data[country_name.title()] = bonds_tmp
    
    # Break on first item ... for testing!
    #break

# Also for testing/debug print value on screen
#print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

# Dump data to file
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_data, outfile)
```